# javascript: Extract elements from array

Tags: javascript

I have no idea whether this should be done or not.

Here is my problem:

I created an function which creates and stores 10 div elemets(with unique IDs).

I want to make another function which would take an array as its parameter and alert the ID of the 5th div(or any particular div element).

Please help

```
function createText(){
    var combo = [];
    for( i =0; i<=5 ; i++) {
        var newText = document.createElement("input");
        newText.type = "text";
        newText.id = "text"+i;
        newText.style.width ="20px";
        newText.style.height ="20px";


        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.type = "div";
        newDiv.id = "div"+i;
        newDiv.style.backgroundColor ="red";
        newDiv.style.cssFloat = "left"; 

        document.getElementById("tryingin").appendChild(newDiv.cloneNode());

        combo.push(document.getElementById("div"+i).appendChild(newText.cloneNode()));
    }

    alert(combo);
}


function alert(arr) {
    //now I want to alert the id of the div(or textbox) here
}
```

Comment: Look up the `array.slice(...)` function

Comment: ok i am checking array.slice()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is wrong.

```
combo.push(document.getElementById("div"+i).appendChild(newText.cloneNode()));
```

Here you add the input to the div and then you add input to the array. [The appendChild method returns a reference to the added node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild).

you need to be doing it in two lines:

```
document.getElementById("div"+i).appendChild(newText.cloneNode());
combo.push(document.getElementById("div"+i));
```

Then you need a function like so:

```
function aklertDivbyIndex(theDivs, index){
    return alert(theDivs[index].id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of divs all with unique ids, a function would look something like this:

```
function alertFifth(listOfDivs) {
  alert(listOfDivs[4].id);
}
```

JavaScript allows for access into arrays by index starting at 0 (as with most modern languages). Note that the fifth element is considered the 4th in CS terms.

Comment: It's still the fifth element of the array, it only resides at index `4`. Unless you're from the "zeroth element" school of thought? :)

Comment: question is `or any particular div element`

Comment: this gives me id of text box. thats fine. i want id of the div